# How to copy text as it is without any processing in Excel?

Tags: excel, text, editor

I copy this text `("","","")`, without brackets, for programming purposes to Excel file in order to manipulate huge code stuff together. But, the problem is that Excel process the copied stuff to `(,"","")` for example. How to copy text as it is without any processing in Excel?

Answer (score 0):

You could try changing the cell format to "Text":

[image]

Comment: I have changed the cell format to "Text". But, the problem still exists, when I copy ("","",""), without brackets, it is pasted as (,"","") not ("","","").

Answer (score 0):

Excel applies on paste of text the CSV standard as described in Wikipedia article [Comma-separated values](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values).

A cell value with commas or double quotes must be enclosed in double quotes and each double quote within the text must be escaped with an additional double quote.

Therefore to get `"","",""` pasted into a cell, the string `""""","""","""""` must be copied to clipboard.